# Explain what does the & meaning in here

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and currently learning about pointers. This was from my notes:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    
int main()
{
    int value1 =5, value2 = 15;
    int *p1, *p2;
    
    p1 = &value1; //why does it mean by the & here?
    p2 = &value2; //and here?
    *p1 = 10;
    *p2 = *p1;
    p1 = p2;
    *p1 = 20;
    
    cout << "Value1 = " << value1 << "Value 2 = " << value2;
    return 0;
}
```

What does the `&` mean here?

Comment: In this context it means "address of". Do you have a textbook or other reference material you can use?

Comment: @NathanPierson does it mean that p1 is addressing the value1 which is equivalent to 5?

Comment: This should be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/2079303

Answer (score 0):

`&` means different things in different contexts.  But in this particular context, it is the [address-of operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access), which returns the memory address of the object specified to its right.  So, in this case, `p1` is being assigned (points to) the memory address of `value1`, and `p2` is being assigned (points to) the memory address of `value2`.